# Multiple threads causing intermittent failure in Insert Statement executed through stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi I am calling a stored procedure from .net code. The stored procedure is calculating certain values based on the parameter send from the .net code. After calculation of certain values, three Insert statements to the same table is executed at the end of the stored procedure. I find that at times these insert statements doesn't insert records in the table. This is quite weird as I have thoroughly checked that the stored procedure is called properly and the parameter is sent across as well. Also when only 1 thread runs the problem doesn't arise. It is only in case I am running 9 multiple threads that is accessing the same stored procedure parallely.

Please suggest if some setting needs to be checked or something that is missing.

I doubt there might be a deadlock situation that is arising and preventing the inserts. But I am not sure. I also checked the allow_row_locks and allow_page_locks in the indexes for the table and these are set as 'ON';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say your code is generating the same values to insert, thus violating the constraints of the table.

Do you have primary keys or unique keys in the table? Maybe there are some checks in triggers in the table that might cause this?

Comment: Hi George I have 1 Pkey that cannot be NULL and should be unique.. I am using a function to generate the PKey each time insert is called.. 

CREATE FUNCTION [Function1](@inValue [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS [nvarchar](16) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
GO

Calling the function from the insert statements as Function1('001')

This should generate unique 16 digit nvarchar each time.. Do you think this might cause any issue?

Comment: Hi Sourav, 
I do not know the logic behind the function to generate the PKEY, but i would definitely suspect it to be cause for your problems.
If it generates different unique result, it means you use some kind of randomization inside. Is it related to the time of the system? If such, you should add some delay before generating the unique response because it is perfectly possible that the function is executed at the same moment in time.
If it is related to some other things (eg plain random) then it is, by itself, dangerous.

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your input. I am still checking on that PKey field. I also feel that this PKey is causing the issue. But still testing the same as well as trying out ways to rectify it. Will post again when it is solved. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: Yes.. So the issue is finally resolved. I changed the logic by which the unique PKey was getting generated. It solved the issue. Though we couldn't go deep into the reason why the earlier logic wasn't working, but tweaking it is giving the expected results. Thank you a lot. :)

Comment: If i could see the code you used to generate the PK, I will give a try at figuring it out, just for the fun of it :)
Anyway, glad to have helped!